# iterate over spatial polygon data frame in R

Tags: r

I am trying to iterate over the rows of a spatial polygon data frame in R, but cannot figure out the right indexing. I don't want to select by attributes, but rather just iterate over the spatial polygon data frame.

Comment: Could you give some sample code, indicate what you've tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not need to apply a conditional subset, you can just use a bracket index on rows, without referencing the @data slot.

```
library(sp)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y

# Subset first observation and plot
p <- meuse[1,]
  plot(meuse, pch=20)
  plot(p, pch=20, cex=1.5, col="red", add=TRUE) 

# display elev value for each observation
for(i in 1:nrow(meuse)) {
  p <- meuse[i,]
  cat("elev", i, p@data$elev, "\n")
}
```

Comment: That is it. I was missing the comma in p <-meuse[1,]

Answer (score 0):

Using the **"split"** function of the base library allows to use ***apply*** -style iterators (faster than "for" loops and much more memory-efficient for big datasets)

e.g :

```
library("rgdal")

shp<-"MY_SHP_PATH"
my_layer <- readOGR(shp , GDAL1_integer64_policy = TRUE)
split_layer=split(my_layer , my_layer$KEY_FIELD)
sapply(split_layer, function(my_geom)
{
   #GET ID
   id<-my_geom$ID_FIELD
   #GET NAME
   name<-my_geom$NAME_FIELD
   #GET elevation
   elevation<-my_geom$ELEVATION_FIELD

   # + to get the geometry (if there is only one polygon shape in the item)
   #...otherwise iterate on "polygons"...
   coords_poly<-my_geom@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@coords

   #etc... 
 })
```

`

This should also work for points ("SpatialPointsDataFrame") and related types...